# Update then insert in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I would like to do an update then insert the same record with a bit modification again under oracle.

### Examples as:

```
    ID NAME                 TEACHER      STATUS         CourseTaken
     1 Jack                     TA          ENROLL         1
     2 Rose                     TA          ENROLL         2
     3 William                  TB          ENROLL         2
     4 Caledon                  TB          ENROLL         2
```

And Say I want to switch Jack from Teacher TA to teacher TB, but meanwhile, keep the record.
So it ends up like

```
    ID NAME                 TEACHER      STATUS         CourseTaken
     1 Jack                     TA          TRANSFERRED        1
     2 Rose                     TA          ENROLL             2
     3 William                  TB          ENROLL             2
     4 Caledon                  TB          ENROLL             2
     5 Jack                     TA          ENROLL
```

There is a fifth row been added, and the first row is updated.
the actual table has way more columns.

So my goal here is to

1. Insert the 5th row as a copy of row 1
2. Update row 1 and row 5
   accordingly

And done in one statement. Is it possible?

It will be in a transaction, @Transactional is annotated on the method. The reason for asking for one statement or constant amount of statement is to avoid N+1 problem, and performance concerns. Since there could be changes on multiple rows.

Comment: By *one query* do you mean a single SQL statement? Is there a reason, apart from either intellectual curiosity or an instructor's requirement that you want to make this  a single statement? Sounds like you need a `SELECT`, `INSERT` and an `UPDATE` statement. And they should be inside a `transaction`.

Comment: It will be in a transaction, @Transactional is annotated on the method. The reason for asking for one statement or constant amount of statement is to avoid N+1 problem, and performance concerns. Since there could be changes on multiple rows.

Comment: one statement, not one query. Corrected.

Comment: This is a cue to use `merge` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I am assumming that `ID` column is a primary key.
If yes, then try:

```
MERGE INTO mytable m
USING (
      SELECT ID, NAME,  TEACHER, STATUS, CourseTaken, d.*
      FROM mytable
      CROSS JOIN (
         SELECT * FROM dual
         UNION ALL
         SELECT null FROM dual
      ) d
      WHERE MyTable.Name = 'Jack'
) p
ON ( p.id = m.id and DUMMY IS NOT NULL )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET STATUS = 'TRANSFERRED'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT( ID, NAME,  TEACHER, STATUS )
     VALUES ( some_sequence.nextval, p.name, p.teacher, 'ENROLL' );
```

I am assumming that you are using `some_sequence` to generate new values for `ID` column.

---

Personally I would do simple `INSERT` and `UPDATE` (as separate commands) in a one transaction, and then commit the whole transaction at the end, instead of using this horrible MERGE.
But if you must use a single command, then you must live with it.